# How to write a file of ASCII bytes to a binary file as actual bytes?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

Trying to do an MD5 collision homework problem and I'm not sure how to write raw bytes in Python. I gave it a shot but just ended up with a .bin file with ASCII in it. Here's my code:

```
fileWriteObject1 = open("md5One.bin", 'wb')
fileWriteObject2 = open("md5Two.bin", 'wb')
fileReadObject1 = open('bytes1.txt', 'r')
fileReadObject2 = open('bytes2.txt', 'r')

bytes1Contents = fileReadObject1.readlines()
bytes2Contents = fileReadObject2.readlines()

fileReadObject1.close()
fileReadObject2.close()


for bytes in bytes1Contents:
    toWrite = r"\x" + bytes
    fileWriteObject1.write(toWrite.strip()) 

for bytes in bytes2Contents:
    toWrite = r"\x" + bytes
    fileWriteObject2.write((toWrite.strip())

fileWriteObject1.close()
fileWriteObject2.close()
```

sample input:
                d1
                31
                dd
                02
                c5
                e6
                ee
                c4
                69
                3d
                9a
                06
                98
                af
                f9
                5c
                2f
                ca
                b5

I had a link to my input file but it seems a mod removed it. It's a file with a hex byte written in ASCII on each line.

EDIT: SOLVED! Thanks to Circumflex.

I had two different text files each with 128 bytes of ASCII. I converted them to binary and wrote them using struck.pack and got a MD5 collision.

Comment: What does your input actually look like? (There's technically no such thing as "ASCII bytes", but there are many ways to represent arbitrary bytes using ASCII characters. You should specify which one you're talking about)

Comment: I had a link to my input file but it seems a mod removed it. It's a file with a hex byte written in ASCII on each line.

Comment: So you need to convert each pair of characters to a byte, and write those to a file. To get started, try `int("d1", base=16)`.

Comment: Isn't an int going to take up a lot more space than a byte?

Comment: @advocate (3 comments up): not a moderator, just an edit by a regular user that probably happened to come at the wrong time. (By the way, there's no need to edit your question to include the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write them as raw bytes, you can use the `pack()` method of the `struct` type.

You could write the MD5 out as 2 long long ints, but you'd have to write it in 2 8 byte sections

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Edit:

An example:

```
import struct

bytes = "6F"
byteAsInt = int(bytes, 16)
packedString = struct.pack('B', byteAsInt)
```

If I've got this right, you're trying to pull in some text with hex strings written, convert them to binary format and output them? If that is the case, that code should do what you want.

It basically converts the raw hex string to an int, then packs it in binary form (as a byte) into a string.

You could loop over something like this for each byte in the input string

Comment: Any chance you could throw an example my way? I'm not sure about the formatting characters. The documentation doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Sure, I've added an example to my answer :)

Comment: This looks perfect. I was also researching the binascii package which uses: binascii.a2b_hex('ee') but it returns a buffer which isn't compatible with the string class so not sure how to save or write the result.

Comment: Instead of ``struct``, use ``encode`` and ``decode``. For example: ``'41'.decode('hex')`` gives you ``A``, and ``'A'.encode('hex')`` gives you ``'41'``.

Comment: But how do you write the result of 'A'.encode('hex') to a file?

Comment: @advocate The way that you were before- the output is a string

Comment: @Nam Nguyen: `str.decode('hex')` uses `binascii.unhexlify()` for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binary = binascii.unhexlify("d131dd02c5")
>>> binary
'\xd11\xdd\x02\xc5'
```

[`binascii.unhexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii#binascii.a2b_hex) is defined in [`binascii.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/binascii.c#l1117). Here's a "close to C" implementation in Python:

```
def binascii_unhexlify(ascii_string_with_hex):
    arglen = len(ascii_string_with_hex) 
    if arglen % 2 != 0:
       raise TypeError("Odd-length string")

    retval = bytearray(arglen//2)
    for j, i in enumerate(xrange(0, arglen, 2)):
        top = to_int(ascii_string_with_hex[i])
        bot = to_int(ascii_string_with_hex[i+1])
        if top == -1 or bot == -1:
           raise TypeError("Non-hexadecimal digit found")
        retval[j] = (top << 4) + bot

    return bytes(retval)

def to_int(c):
    assert len(c) == 1
    return "0123456789abcdef".find(c.lower())
```

If there were no `binascii.unhexlify()` or `bytearray.fromhex()` or `str.decode('hex')` or similar you could write it as follows:

```
def unhexlify(s, table={"%02x" % i: chr(i) for i in range(0x100)}):
    if len(s) % 2 != 0: 
        raise TypeError("Odd-length string")
    try:
        return ''.join(table[top+bot] for top, bot in zip(*[iter(s.lower())]*2))
    except KeyError, e:
        raise TypeError("Non-hexadecimal digit found: %s" % e)
```